# violates check constraint

Tags: postgis, linestring

I try to add a constraint based on geometry type to a "street" table that prevents anything except Linestring geometry or Null.

```
alter table streets
add constraint streets_geom_linestring_chk
check(st_geometrytype(geom) = 'ST_LINESTRING'::text OR geom IS NULL);
```

When I try to store geometries in the table:

```
update streets set geom=st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(0 8,12 8)') where id=1;
```

I got an error, that the new row for relation violates check constraint.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a more descriptive title. Titles should be written as questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ST_GeometryType](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_GeometryType.html) returns 'ST_Linestring', 'ST_Polygon','ST_MultiPolygon' etc. You can change check to use [GeometryType](http://postgis.org/docs/GeometryType.html) which return mentioned values without ST_ prefix

Comment: Yes of course, the solution is the st_ prefix in the geometrytype function. I had already tried to remove the st_ in linestring and add a st_ at the input. sometimes the solution is so simple. many thanks for the quick response.