# Check constraint on geometry column is not working as expected

Tags: postgis, postgresql, constraint

I am going through the QGIS Training Manual (16.5.2) and could not figure out why the streets table throws a violation check error as trying to update a geometry column. I checked a very similar question at [violates check constraint](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87498/violates-check-constraint) but couldn't get any clue. I understand "GeometryType" has been upgraded to "ST_GEOMETRYTYPE".

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look closely at both your `CHECK` constraint definition and the [function docs](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryType.html): `ST_GeometryType` returns the actual type (following the `ST_` prefix) **formatted in *PascalCase***, i.e. `ST_LineString`!

You'd want to recreate that `CHECK` like so:

```
ALTER TABLE streets
  DROP CONSTRAINT enforce_geometry_chk
;

ALTER TABLE streets
  ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_geometry_chk
    CHECK (ST_GeometryType(geom) = 'ST_LineString'::TEXT OR geom IS NULL)
;
```

---

**However:**

While you may get some insights in managing table `CONTRAINT`s following that tutorial, PostGIS type enforcing mechanisms have evolved significantly since it was written (which, apparently, was a looong time ago...), and by now the suggested table set-up violates best practices.

The two PostGIS specific types `GEOMETRY` and `GEOGRAPHY` allow for an explicit definition of the *geometry type* when used as column definition, as well as the SRID you want to enforce[¹] on your geometries, e.g. [²]:

```
CREATE TABLE streets (
  id     INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  "name" VARCHAR(50),
  geom   GEOMETRY(LINESTRING, 4326)
);
```

While in the early versions of PostGIS this was indeed realized by adding `CHECK` contraints during table creation, it now is implemented via the PostgreSQL *type modificator* system - an addition to core data types that allows direct enforcement of dynamic, type specific restrictions (see e.g. `VARCHAR(50)`)

The above set up follows current best practices, and has the intended behaviour - except that it also checks the SRID of the `INSERT`ed/`UPDATE`ted geometries. In your case, since you use the EWKT string representation with attached SRID, it will just work.

---

[¹]: *enforce* really means *checked against*: it will not do anything to solve issues - it just raises an error like yours

[²]: Note here that, except for `"name"` which is wrapped in `"`, all other **identifiers** and **SQL keywords** are *case insensitive*, so the above is equivalent to

```
create table streets (
  id     int generated by default as identity primary key,
  "name" varchar(50),
  geom   geometry(linestring, 4326)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I could figure out this issue on my own. ST_LineString is case sensitive and must be typed exactly as it is.

```
CHECK(ST_GeometryType(geom) = 'ST_LineString'::text
```

And I guess that so are all of this type of constants.
I still do not understand why it is not throwing an 'invalid geometry' error when typed with the right spelling but without the proper case.(ie. ST_Linestring)

Comment: Because that `CHECK` constraint really **only compares two strings** for equality! There is no geometry check involved, the geometry doesn't get toughed by this update at all - and the actual geometry is totally valid.